# Anyone know how can I obtain the database schema of peachtree with SQL? (pervasive)

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm trying to create a query that returns me the schema of the database peachtree erp. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Until now, I could get this: `Select * from X$File` 
but It's not what I need.

Or if anyone has a modeling database for peachtree, it would be nice to share it over here.

Answer (score 0):

The `X$FILE` table only stores the table name to physical filename link.  The `X$FIELD` table links the fields to the tables and includes the offsets, data types, and field names.  `X$INDEX` shows the indexes on the fields in `X$FIELD`.

This may or may not help as Peachtree may or may not define all fields or tables.

Comment: Yes, bro. But, I need some standard sql for any database peachtree. My intention is some reverse engineering.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment.  Once you have the tables (from X$FILE), you can use the table ID to get the fields from X$FIELD.  If you've got a recent version of Peachtree, it might be using a newer version of Pervasive / Actian and you might be able to use the System Stored Procedures (http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/catalogfuncs.htm) to get some of this information.